# mousedown on a control and mousemove on another

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, mouseevent, creation

I want to create a little diagraming tool, and i'm stuck on a mouse problem.

I have 2 custom control, one for a node, and one for the edge arrow.

The Node custom control is a border placed onto a grid.
I can drag my node around clicking on the border part and create an arrow with mousedown on the grid part.

What i want is to resize the arrow and make it follow the mouse (drag fake) when i fire mousedown on the grid part.

But for now all the mouse event handlers are in the node custom control, since i'll have another behavior when clicking on the arrow custom control.

I don't need library answers, cause i want to implement it myself.

Any guess ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! it wasn't a wpf problem but a coding one, the border and grid MouseEvents were sharing a variable i didn't see, and i had curious behaviors but everything's fine now